# OSM map crashes random on loading Tile image in android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, kotlin, osmdroid

App crashes randomly on loading the OSM map tile image stating **error** in log as continuously

**Failed to open file '/data/data/packageName/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/14/4294/6311.png': No such file or directory**

This was mainly found on Android 11

**Console recorded the crash as:**
backtrace:
#00  pc 000000000003c200  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::AssetManager2::Open(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, android::Asset::AccessMode) const+140)
#00  pc 0000000000121e14  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeOpenAsset(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, _jstring*, int)+484)
#00  pc 00000000002351ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+188)
#00  pc 0000000002081258  /memfd:jit-cache (android.content.res.AssetManager.open+136)
#00  pc 0000000002095754  /memfd:jit-cache (android.content.res.AssetManager.open+52)
#00  pc 000000000208dd64  /memfd:jit-cache (org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileAssetsProvider$TileLoader.loadTile+260)
#00  pc 000000000208d984  /memfd:jit-cache (org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.loadTileIfReachable+116)
#00  pc 0000000002053c1c  /memfd:jit-cache (org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase$TileLoader.run+636)
#00  pc 0000000002080108  /memfd:jit-cache (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+408)
#00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
#00  pc 00000000001a9a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
#00  pc 000000000032129c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
#00  pc 00000000003175c8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996)
#00  pc 00000000006862d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+848)
#00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
#00  pc 00000000001f8eb0  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+4)
#00  pc 0000000000687fb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1808)
#00  pc 000000000012ea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
#00  pc 0000000000003330  [anon:dalvik-/apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar-transformed] (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
#00  pc 000000000030ebc4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16619280533006879875)+268)
#00  pc 0000000000674d5c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780)
#00  pc 000000000013dff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
#00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
#00  pc 00000000001a9a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
#00  pc 000000000055e278  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesart::ArtMethod*(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460)
#00  pc 00000000005ada3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1308)
#00  pc 00000000000eb7a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
#00  pc 000000000008bc8c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)